# Assigning attributes to elements of a empty set

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering if one could assign random attributes to the elements empty sets, even contradictions. Because there are no elements, I can say something like:

$\forall x \in \emptyset.P(x) \land \neg P(x)$

Hence a set containing contradictions for all elements must be empty, I can assign any attribute (even its opposite).

Is my reasoning wrong, or is this just the way it is and it shouldn't be mind-boggling?

Comment: I don't have a background in logic (at all), but I'm pretty sure that for all $x\in\varnothing$, it is true that $Q(x)$ regardless of the details of $Q$. We certainly act like this is true in less formal contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Hence a set containing contradictions for all elements must be empty"

The empty set doesn't contain any element, so it doesn't contain propositions that are  contradictions.

But it is true that $\forall x \in \varnothing : P(x) \land Q(x)$. That is, $$\forall x: x\in \varnothing \rightarrow (P(x) \land \lnot P(x)).$$ Since there is no $x \in \varnothing$, $x\in \varnothing \rightarrow (P(x) \land \lnot P(x))$ is vacuously true for any (every) such (nonexisting) $x$.

Perhaps what you mean to be saying is:

- $\varnothing = \{x \mid P(x) \land \neg P(x)\}:\;\;$ "The set of all $x$ such that $P(x) \land \lnot P(x)$." 
  Since there is no $x$ such that $P(x) \land \lnot P(x)$, the empty set remains empty.

The empty set can be defined by *any condition(s) that no element can satisfy*.

Examples:

- $\varnothing = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 = -1\}$
- $\varnothing = \{x \mid x + 3 = x\}$
- See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45117/what-is-a-null-set), too.

---

Note: every *universal* statement about the elements of the empty set is true; this is known as [***vacuous truth***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). One might say that universal statements are "***true until proven false.***" Since there are NO elements in the empty set, such statements ***cannot*** be proven false (as there is no element to serve as a counterexample).

Comment: Would the following statement then be true, or is it not even a proper statement?
All elements of the empty set are even numbers.

Comment: Yes, that would be *vacuously true*: as would be "all elements of the empty set are odd numbers."

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't came across the concept of vacuous truth, great explanation!

Comment: Christian You're welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: I think your first sentence is misleading. The issue is not whether the empty set contains any propositions, the issue is whether its elements can have properties that contradict each other.

Comment: @Michael: I highlighted what I meant to be addressing: the statement used by the OP. Then I addressed the logical expression the OP was commenting on, which is true.

Comment: @amWhy If you formalize logic in set theory, then the set of all contradictions will be nonempty and none f its elements will have contradictory properties. OP has simply not mentioned sets of propositions.

Comment: The empty set is $\emptyset$ or what you noted? Which symbol? +

Comment: @Babak both symbols work for the empty set: $\varnothing$ = `\varnothing`; and $\emptyset$ = `\emptyset`. It's just a matter of preference, but both denote "the empty set".$\quad$  :-)

Comment: @amWhy: They had a bad attack on me. I didn't have any support there. Enclosed to anything.....

Answer (score 3):

It is worth pointing out that in most formalization of logic, "$\forall x\in\varnothing:P(x)$" is considered an abbreviation of
$$ \forall x: (x\in\varnothing \to P(x)) $$

Since $x\in\varnothing$ is always false for every $x$, the implication $x\in\varnothing\to P(x)$ is always *true* (because the only way $Q\to P$ can be false is when $Q$ is true and $P$ is false), and therefore the entire quantified formula is true.